# Extracting MP3 Album artwork in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

I have been trying to extract metadata information from a .mp3 file for an iPhone app. I tried using `AVAsset` like [this](http://www.arlt.eu/blog/2010/11/30/enumerating-metadata-of-avassets-in-ios/).It didn't work,the common meta data is empty. But audacity and another iOS app from app store could retrieve the meta data details. I don't know why?.

So, I tried to extract the same with below code using `AudioToolBox` framework

```
    CFDictionaryRef piDict = nil;
    UInt32 piDataSize = sizeof(piDict);

    //  Populates a CFDictionary with the ID3 tag properties
    err = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &piDataSize, &piDict);
    if(err != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"AudioFileGetProperty failed for property info dictionary");
        return nil;
    }

    //  Toll free bridge the CFDictionary so that we can interact with it via objc
    NSMutableDictionary* nsDict = [(__bridge NSDictionary*)piDict mutableCopy];
```

This returned everything except album art. When I tried to extract the album art using `kAudioFilePropertyAlbumArtwork` , I got `osstatus` error(The operation couldn't be completed).

So at last, I tried my luck with `ObjC` wrapper for libId3(found [here](https://github.com/rjyo/libid3-ios)). It worked perfectly well. I could get the artwork.

My question is, why `AVAsset` could not retrieve the data?. What am I missing there?. somebody managed to to get it work?. A sample will be appreciated.

Why `kAudioFilePropertyAlbumArtwork` extraction couldn't be completed?. Both the issues happened with all the .mp3 files I had.

**Solution Update:**

`AVAsset` didn't work for me because I made my URL using

```
 [NSURL URLWithString:[filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

rather than

```
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use AVAsset to extract metadata informations, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030746/ios-avfoundation-how-do-i-fetch-artwork-from-an-mp3-file) is useful. The following code is what you need:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"commonMetadata", nil];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
    NSArray *artworks = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:asset.commonMetadata
                                                       withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork
                                                      keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon];

    for (AVMetadataItem *item in artworks) {
        if ([item.keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceID3]) {
            NSDictionary *dict = [item.value copyWithZone:nil];
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[dict objectForKey:@"data"]];
        } else if ([item.keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes]) {
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[item.value copyWithZone:nil]];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: I checked the post already. My problem is "commonMetadata" return empty array. I mean no "keys". But information is there and I could extract the same with audiotoolbox. It happens with all the mp3 file I have.

Comment: I used this code and it extract the albumArt perfectly. Can you link a mp3 file you used or maybe your code?

Comment: I can link the mp3 file I used. I tried the same code you have pasted above.The link(http://starmusiq.com/Composer.asp?Composer=A.R.Rahman&RecNextPg=4) has few mp3 files, you can try with anything.

Comment: FYI, I have file downloaded.I was not streaming.can you link your .mp3 file I can try that.

Comment: I downloaded a .mp3 file from that site and test it... Everything works well. Here is the code: http://www.4shared.com/zip/SW9p8k85/removeMe.html

Comment: +1 for your time. It does work. But I am not sure y it didn't work for me. I think its got to do with something in my app. Thank you.

Comment: What if I have a image url or server path of image ?

Comment: I have an mp3 in the `AVMetadataKeySpaceID3` `keySpace`, but I'm finding that `item.value` *is* the image data, not a dictionary wrapper around the image data -- can anyone provide a link to a source on how to definitively extract this data?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileURL1];


for (AVMetadataItem *metadataItem in asset.commonMetadata) {
    if ([metadataItem.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){
        NSDictionary *imageDataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)metadataItem.value;
        NSData *imageData = [imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        imageThumb.image = image;
    }
}
```