# Conversion of raw music file from main bundle to MPMediaItem

Tags: ios, iphone, media-player, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

is there any way I can get reference of MPMediaItem from raw mp3 file bundled in main bundle as a resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) is a file in the iPod library. It is clearly stated in the documentation:

> A media item represents a single piece of media (such as one song or
>   one video podcast) in the iPod library.

Comment: Lightening fast man !!! thanks for the info... then is there any way I can retrieve artist info, song info and other properties from song with out using MPMediaItem cause I know how to use MPMediaItem to retrieve them. Please help me out.

Comment: Yes that is possible, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030746/ios-avfoundation-how-do-i-fetch-artwork-from-an-mp3-file/14046486#14046486

Comment: Okay..I will give it a try and come back to let you know however u r damn good!!!!