# Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'AVMetadataKey'

Tags: swift4

I'm trying to convert my Swift 3 code to Swift 4. I get this error message:

Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'AVMetadataKey'

```
private extension JukeboxItem.Meta {
mutating func process(metaItem item: AVMetadataItem) {

    switch item.commonKey
    {
    case "title"? :
        title = item.value as? String
    case "albumName"? :
        album = item.value as? String
    case "artist"? :
        artist = item.value as? String
    case "artwork"? :
        processArtwork(fromMetadataItem : item)
    default :
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please <kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on `commonKey` and you will see that the argument is of type `AVMetadataKey` rather than `String`.

You are encouraged to read the documentation. It's worth it and you can fix yourself an issue like this in seconds.

I added a `guard` statement to exit the method immediately if `commonKey` is `nil`.

```
private extension JukeboxItem.Meta {
    func process(metaItem item: AVMetadataItem) {

        guard let commonKey = item.commonKey else { return }
        switch commonKey 
        {
        case .commonKeyTitle :
            title = item.value as? String
        case .commonKeyAlbumName :
            album = item.value as? String
        case .commonKeyArtist :
            artist = item.value as? String
        case .commonKeyArtwork :
            processArtwork(fromMetadataItem : item)
        default :
            break
        }
    }
}
```