# how to use object c extract mp3 file metadata?

Tags: objective-c, avurlasset

AVURLAsset can extract mp3 file metadata , but when a mp3 file extension name not '.mp3' , The AVURLAsset can't get the metadata . how can i get the extesion name not '.mp3' file metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if I understand your question, is it: "how can I extract metadata from files that do not have the mp3 extension"?

I don't believe there is a limitation by extension, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884067/how-can-i-extract-metadata-from-mp3-file-in-ios-development) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030746/ios-avfoundation-how-do-i-fetch-artwork-from-an-mp3-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318821/extracting-mp3-album-artwork-in-ios)  (grin;-)